# Error occurred while trying to proxy request with Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I'm a bit of an Angular newbie and am having problems starting my local development server. I'm not sure it's relevant but, I am running the MongoDB database from Siteground. The documentation informs me to open sourcecode/proxy.conf.json file and update target url there to the base url of the site. For example: http://localhost/my-site.

This is the terminal error I am getting when running 'npm start'. Any help would be greatly appreciated..

> [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request
>   /secure/bootstrap-data?original_url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2F
>   from localhost:4200 to http://localhost/mtdb/server (ECONNREFUSED)
>   (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)

My proxy.config.json file is below, however I'm not sure how this should be updated.

```
{
"/secure": {
"target": "http://localhost/mtdb/server",
"secure": false
},
"/__clockwork": {
"target": "http://localhost/mtdb/server/public",
"secure": false
},
"/mtdb/server/public": {
"target": "http://localhost",
"secure": false
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be it is because you didn't define your port.

It should be like that

```
target: 'http://localhost:3000'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the port like this:

```
target: 'http://localhost:4200'
```

Comment: Hmmm unfortunatey neither :4200 or :3000 have worked.

Comment: @unicorn_surprise how did you solve it then?

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart your server. I had the same problem then I restarted my WAMP server and it worked smoothly.